# How to validate joomla 2.5 default text editor?

Tags: jquery, joomla, validation, joomla2.5

how to validate joomla default text editor on blur using jQuery?

This is the code what I used get text editor. Example, in /models/forms/newsitem.xml:

```
    <field name="description" type="editor" buttons="true" 
                   hide="pagebreak,readmore,article,image"
                   class="inputbox required"
                   filter="JComponentHelper::filterText"
                   label="JGLOBAL_DESCRIPTION" 
                   description="COM_NEWSITEMS_FIELD_DESCRIPTION_DESC" required="true" />
```

And the second file (/views/.../edit.php) - What new object to add to the javascript?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Joomla.submitbutton = function(task) {
        if (task == 'newsitem.cancel' || document.formvalidator.isValid(document.id('newsitem-form'))) {
            <?php echo $this->form->getField('description')->save(); ?>
            Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('newsitem-form'));
        } else {
            alert('<?php echo $this->escape(JText::_('JGLOBAL_VALIDATION_FORM_FAILED'));?>');
        }
    }
</script>
```

What I want is I want to show a warning message next to text editor saying "you can't leave this blank". I can do it in form submit but real challenge is how to do it on blur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it. Changed answer (login- **Irfan**), but it should be - if you click "Save", then the editor displays an error (empty text). Here's an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    Joomla.submitbutton = function(task) {
        if (task == 'newsitem.cancel' || document.formvalidator.isValid(document.id('newsitem-form'))) {
          if(task != 'newsitem.cancel') {
            var boolSubmit = true;
            if(jQuery('#jform_description_parent').is(':visible')) {
                jQuery(jQuery('#jform_description_parent iframe')[0].contentWindow).each(function() {
                    var editor_text = jQuery('#jform_description_parent iframe').contents().find('body').text();
                    if(editor_text=='') {
                        alert('<?php echo $this->escape(JText::_('JGLOBAL_VALIDATION_FORM_FAILED'));?>');
                        boolSubmit = false
                    }
                });
            } else {
                jQuery('textarea#jform_description').each(function() {
                    if(jQuery(this).val()=='') {
                        alert('<?php echo $this->escape(JText::_('JGLOBAL_VALIDATION_FORM_FAILED'));?>');
                        boolSubmit = false;
                    }
                });
            }
            if(!boolSubmit)
               return boolSubmit;
          }
          <?php echo $this->form->getField('description')->save(); ?>            
          Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('newsitem-form'));
        } else {
            alert('<?php echo $this->escape(JText::_('JGLOBAL_VALIDATION_FORM_FAILED'));?>');
        }
    }
</script>
```

All right conclusion? I think that may all right.

Answer (score 0):

This code `document.formvalidator.isValid(document.id('newsitem-form'))` validates your form if only editor is there in the form you can try this-

```
jQuery('#editorid').blur(function() {
  if(!document.formvalidator.isValid(document.id('newsitem-form'))){
    //Add your error message code 

  }
});
```

**Update**:-

```
jQuery(jQuery('iframe')[0].contentWindow).blur(function() {
 var editor_text = jQuery('iframe').contents().find('body').text();
 if(editor_text=='')alert('Error message');
});
```

Note:-Use the valid selector that points to  editor iframe this will only work if there is one editor

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi, Irfan. It is impossible. There's no error output. For example, I wrote - $('#jform_description').blur... But does not appear 'required' in class (editor in admin) of XML. Help, please. I need to. I await your reply

Comment: I forgot to say. It was installed JCE

Comment: @Areku_UA:I have updated my answer may be this will guide you.

Comment: Hey. I came up to change your answer, it turned out. See my answer.
Thanks in advance!